# npm start-react-app test does not create described folder structure

Tags: node.js, npm

I would like to build a small static homepage and follow some tutorials. However, `npx` does not act as described.

I installed npm with miniconda:

```
conda create -n react nodejs
```

I updated `npm` on and Ubuntu 20.04 system with

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

and also tried

```
npm install -g npm@next
```

##### (Updated)

Then I ran

```
npm create-react-app homepage  
# turned out I had a typo here. 
# Using npx instead of npm works!
```

The created folder does not look as described [here](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/how-to-create-a-react-app) or [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-react-project-with-create-react-app-in-10-steps/).

There is no `src` folder and no `README` either. Only this items:

```
node_modules  package.json  package-lock.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the problem comes from some missing statements in the tutorials.

I had to

```
npm init
npm install create-react-app
npx create-react-app homepage
```

And now everything is as expected.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I typed `npm crate-react-app homepage` and not `npx`.